# Parameterization of an array of enums?

Tags: node-postgres

I have a table where one of the fields is an array of enums. For example let say this is what it looks like:

```sql
CREATE TYPE foobar AS ENUM (
  'FOO',
  'BAR'
);

CREATE TABLE my_table (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  foobarray foobar[] DEFAULT ARRAY['FOO']::foobar[]
);
```

When I try to use `node-postgres` to insert/update a row it is not clear how to parameterize the array and get it type cast to an array of enums.

When I try:

```js
const foobarray = ["BAR"];
await pool.query("UPDATE my_table SET foobarray=$2::foobar[] WHERE id=$1", [id, foobarray]);
```

I get:

```
error: invalid input value for enum foobarray: "{"
```

Any ideas how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my issue...

I was actually pulling the value, before updating it, as follows:

```sql
SELECT foobarray FROM my_table WHERE id=$1;
```

This resulted in the following array being in the result:

```js
["{", "}", "FOO"]
```

I didn't realize this and was trying to modify the array from the result before updating which resulted in `"{"` and `"}"` which are obviously not valid ENUM values being passed through.

I was able to solve this issue by keeping my original `UPDATE` query the same but modifying the `SELECT` query to:

```sql
SELECT foobarray::text[] FROM my_table WHERE id=$1;
```

This results in the following array being in the result:

```js
["FOO"]
```

Tweaking it and updating now causes no problems.